# Custom LayoutManager disallow touch event for child views except first one

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a custom `LayoutManager` that relays views like a card stack as follows. However, I am having a problem with touch event. I'd like to only allow the first child to have a `touch event` and disallow for other ones. How can I make it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I usually add the following in my XML layout files to disallow touches in any fragments behind the current one.

```
<!-- Add the following in your parent container -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...
  android:clickable="true"
  android:focusable="true" />
```

Comment: No, this is a library I am currently developing and shouldn't design at someone's sweet will. I created a custom layout manager to add childs

Comment: Ah... I see... Is there a way for you to set these properties true/false to the view and try when you are adding/removing a child?

Comment: Tried disable onTouch event each time adding item. What is strange it affects all views.